# Error in Gradle Building in android studio 3.1.1

Tags: android, migration, build.gradle, jcenter

Since I migrated to ***Android Studio 3.1.1***, I encountered this problem during the Bilding :

***Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.1.0/gradle-3.1.0.Pom'***

Is there a problem  in Jcenter?

Please help, thanks

build.gradle file:
[image]

Comment: Are you connected to the internet?

Comment: Did you set the google repo? The gradle plugin 3.1.0 is not in jcenter.

Comment: Yes, I'm connected to the internet and set Google repository in build.gradle file , @GabrieleMariotti

Comment: can you post your build.gradle?

Comment: i added one image of build.gradle file to my post _@GabrieleMariotti

Comment: What is the full error that you are getting? are you using Artifactory as your binary repository manager and reaching JCenter via Artifactory? If so, what do you see in the Artifactory logs after the failing request?